# Copy file in a library to a folder in another library with Workflow

Tags: document-library, designer-workflow, copy-and-paste

I using SharePoint Online 2013 and Workflow 2013.

I need copy a file in the library "A", folder "Test1" to the library "B" to the folder "Test2". I need do this using Workflow.

In the function "copy" of the workflow, I can't define the path of the file.

Can I define a path in Action/Function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this using out of the box workflow actions. I don't know any 3rd party workflow actions set which works with SharePoint 2013 workflows and allows to copy documents. There are only custom actions for SharePoint 2010 workflows.

For now you have three options:

- To break your head with [Call HTTP web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558%28v=office.15%29.aspx) workflow action. You can try to call REST service to copy files. But this is painful, there is not guarantee that you will achieve your task. You can look at [Files and folders Rest API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841%28v=office.15%29.aspx).
- To create custom workflow action programmatically.
- To use 3rd party workflow action for SharePoint 2010 workflow and to [call it using interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj670125%28v=office.15%29.aspx) from SharePoint 2013 workflow. You can look at [HarePoint workflow actions](http://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointWorkflowExtensions/Default.aspx).

I and my team are working on [Workflow Actions Pack for SharePoint 2013 workflows](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/), we have such workflow action in our roadmap, but we have not had time to implement it yet. You can contact us to sign up for release.

**Update:** We released [document processing workflow actions](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/) for SharePoint 2013 and Office 365. Read [blog article](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/how-to/move%20documents.html) for details.

Comment: Actually, I think your REST suggestion is a good one. We use this in some of our workflows without problems, and they are easy to test out. There might even be an endpoint for copy

Comment: I added the link to REST API reference into my reply. This is new API from MS, I'm not sure it is on premise version yet.

Comment: "On premise" as in local installs? Well yes, it is all over the place, including but not unique to 365.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using default workflow actions.  It's a bit tricky though.

First you have to have an extra column in your document type.  I've added "Resource Identifier" to my default document type.

Then as part of the workflow action you set the resource identifier column to a specific value, say 'XX'

Then you copy the document to the other library.

Then you do an update item on the destination library.  You filter for all documents that have resource identifier 'XX' and then update the path and name field to be your folder `Test2/[%Current Item:Name%]`.  Then you need to also erase the resource identifier on the document so that it doesn't get processed on the next run.