# Copy Functionality Classic View Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, copy

Hi All is there way we can modify Copy functionality of classic view , iwant to implement two functionality , able to set default value of Destination Library and update CopyDateColumn  to Todays once we copy the document in both source and destination file

Is this possible in classic View Copy?

Answer (score 0):

For OOB approaches, I can only think of using Flow or workflow to update list column.

You can establish a new flow to copy files between libraries and update the "CopyDateColumn" to today's date. However it will not work in classic experience.

As 2010 workflow is retiring, you will need to use 2013 workflow to send http request action to send request to Rest API. There are no built-in actions to copy documents

Reference:[Copy file in a library to a folder in another library with Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95730/copy-file-in-a-library-to-a-folder-in-another-library-with-workflow)